# Displaying Profile List as Buttons

Tags: java, class, button

I have created a simple Profile class which takes a name String and age int. If the user creates 2 profiles how can I display them in buttons so they can select a profile. Also how would I update the buttons if the the user deletes or creates a new profile.

Here is the Profile class I have

```
class Profile {

String name;
int age;

public Profile(String name, int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public Profile(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public Profile(int age){
    this.age = age;
}

public Profile(){

}

private void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

private String getName(){
    return name;
}

private void setAge(int age){
    this.age = age;
}

private int getAge(){
    return age;
}
}
```

and I have a profiles List which is updated every time the user creates an account, so how could I display multiple profiles as buttons so the user can select a profile?

Answer (score 0):

U can create ProfileList class and add methods like addProfile(Profile p), showProfile(JFrame window)
and what ur using awt, swing ???